# select row from orc snappy table in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have created a table employee_orc which is orc format with snappy compression.

```
    create table employee_orc(emp_id string, name string)
 row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as orc tblproperties("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

I have uploaded data into the table using the insert statement.

```
employee_orc table has 1000 records.
```

When I run the below query, it shows all the records

```
select * from employee_orc;
```

But when run the below query, it shows zero results even though the records exist.

```
select * from employee_orc where emp_id = "EMP456";
```

Why I am unable to retrieve a single record from the employee_orc table?

Answer (score 0):

The record does *not* exist.  You may think they are the same because they look the same, but there is some difference.  One possibility are spaces at the beginning or end of the string.  For this, you can use `like`:

```
where emp_id like '%EMP456%'
```

This might help you.

Comment: It does not work. Do we need to follow any settings for fetching a single record from snappy compressed ORC table in the hive?

Answer (score 0):

On my part, I don't understand why you want to specify a delimiter in ORC. Are you confusing CSV and ORC or external vs managed ?
I advice you to create your table differently

create table employee_orc(emp_id string, name string)
stored as ORC 
TBLPROPERTIES (
"orc.compress"="ZLIB");

Comment: I have done it. But Still not able to retrieve a single record from the table using where clause. But, I am able to retrieve all the records from the table.

Comment: can you verify the output of select 'A'||emp_id||'A' from employee_orc limit 10;